# Issue on polymer .click() with tactile desktop

Tags: javascript, polymer

I'm currently stuck with a tactile desktop screen ( 27"),
I've got some paper-icons-buttons which trigger a polymer function simulating a .click() on an DOM element. But the .click() doesn't work...

I've put a console.log() inside the function, and the console.log() appears each time on the developper tools...

My function works very well on smartphone (cordova or chrome) and non-tactile desktop.

```
var goToLink = function(url, that) {
    var backLink = (document.createElement('a'));
    backLink.setAttribute('href', url);
    that.appendChild(backLink);
    backLink.click(); // <-- here is the problem
    that.removeChild(backLink);
};
```

Thanks

Comment: probably need more information here, why manipulate the DOM to achieve this functionality? why remove the hyperlink? is url the same page with an anchor? is this in the context of a spa framework?

Comment: For some reasons I have to do this kind of stuff. Could you just forget the "weird" way to achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For `<a>`:

> The click() method will not cause an  element to initiate
>   navigation as if a real mouse-click had been received.

From [MDN docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/click)

So don't expect it to work everywhere.